# SpriteKit SKLabelNode font size to pixels

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit

What's a clean way to use SKLabelNode's fontSize to map to pixels?  I'm trying to place text inside a box that fits in a fixed box proportionately.

Comment: Are you trying to determine which font size to use to ensure that an arbitrary string fits in a fixed size rect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to apple's documentation, 1 font point is equal to 2 pixels.

For example, a 90 pixel font is equal to `mytext.fontSize = 90 / 2`